# Limit twig loop

Tags: php, loops, twig

How can I make the following iteration list 5 items max only?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled childs_2">  
{% set wi = 0 %}
{% for wi in wi..category.children[i]['children_level2']|length %}
<li><a href="{{ category.children[i]['children_level2'][wi]['href'] }}">
{{ category.children[i]['children_level2'][wi]['name'] }}</a>
</li>  
{% endfor %}        
</ul>
```

Answer (score 13):

I think [iterating over a subset](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-a-subset) may work for what you're doing here. With that approach, the `wi` variable shouldn't be necessary, unless you're using it for something else as well.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled childs_2">  
{% for child in category.children[i]['children_level2']|slice(0, 5) %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ child['href'] }}">{{ child['name'] }}</a>
    </li>  
{% endfor %}        
</ul>
```